# How to insert the output of previous command into current command line?

Tags: bash

```
$ pidof qqq
12345
$ cd /proc/
           ^ cursor here
```

And now I want to auto-insert the previous line here. Of course I can manually type `12345` or `` `pidof qqq` ``, but how to do it conveniently?

The question is not solely about `pidof` and `/proc`, but about any such situation of reusing previous command output.

Comment: What are you aiming at? `cd /proc/12345`?

Comment: Yes, for example.

Comment: Related: [bash - automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable)

Comment: `cd /proc/$(pidof qqq)`

Comment: @RahulPatil What shall I press to avoid manually typing `$(pidof qqq)` or copying? The whole point is to save typing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
cd /proc/$(!!)
```

Comment: That is just rerunning the previous command which _could_ output something different the second time it is ran.

Comment: Or \`!!` - even easier to type (if there is no backticks in previous command).

Comment: @llua Good point, the command might also have some other undesirable side-effects (e.g. script which starts a daemon and outputs the pid of the newly created process).

Comment: Maybe the correct implementation should be on side of pseudo-terminal master? I.e. it should be gnome-terminal's (or whatever) shortcut like "Insert penultimate line here". Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10059590/266720